# "Type is missing the following properties, context, setState" when having React Component as argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My use case is pretty simple, I want to have a dynamic react component and save that in a registry:

```js
import { Component } from 'react';
import DummyComponent from './DummyComponent';

class Registry {
  TestComponent: Component = DummyComponent;
}
```

`DummyComponent.tsx:`

```js
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class DummyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    throw new Error('Cannot use this dummy component');
  }
}
```

This is throwing a TypeScript error: `ts(2740): Type 'typeof DummyComponent' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.`

What am I doing wrong? I only want `Registry.TestComponent` to be a React component, it does not have to have all those properties since they're not required for a React component.

I made a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-aa73j8) to show the error. The error is slightly different, but I believe it to be the same issue.

`tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Component` type is an instance of component class, while `DummyComponent` is a class itself.

It should be:

```
class Registry {
  TestComponent: ComponentClass = DummyComponent;
}
```

In case `TestComponent` isn't limited to class components, it is:

```
class Registry {
  TestComponent: ComponentType = DummyComponent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! That fixed it, should have known the distinction.